# Is there any way to remove this "extra line of pixel"?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

So when creating a full width and min-height 100vh div to fill the entire screen, there is this extra line of white pixel at the bottom of the page while inspecting in chrome. I have tried

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

And I have also tried setting the div element's margin and padding to 0

This is the whole div:

```
<div
      className="w-full h-full min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center m-0 p-0"
      style={{
        background: "url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
      }}
    >
```

And this is what the extra line of pixel looks like:
[Image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrSYN.png)

Thanks!

Comment: It's not much code, but what I see looks good for now. I therefore suspect that the white line is a border or rather comes from the background image.

Comment: Chrome devtools can sometimes show issues that aren't there, such as overflow. Does the issue appear on other browsers as well?

Comment: Provide an image of bg.jpg as sometimes images have a tiny white line on the edge